# How do I write a custom silent rule in automake?

Tags: makefile, automake

I'm working on an automake project and we have a custom assembler, compiler, and linker.

Currenlty building those custom targets shows the entire command line:

```
knucc -c -L/some/path/here -I/some/path/include -I/some/other/path -o foobar.o foobar.knucpp
```

How do I sprinkle in the magic to transform the above into this:

```
KCXX foobar.o
```

when I do `make V=0` or turn on the silent rules by default with `configure --enable-silent-rules`.

I'm using automake v1.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found the magic on the GNU automake mailing list: http://gnu-automake.7480.n7.nabble.com/AM-V-GEN-better-docs-td3426.html

I was able to work this out:

```
QUIET_KCXX = $(QUIET_KCXX_$(V))
QUIET_KCXX_ = $(QUIET_KCXX_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
QUIET_KCXX_0 = @printf "  %-5s    " KCXX ; echo $(notdir $@);

.knucxx.o:
    $(QUIET_KCXX) # build command here
```

and now I have a custom message during silent builds.